# Fffmpeg while loop stops before all files are processed

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a list of 3k URLs in a text file named "downloadmp3.txt", with the following format:

```
url1,filename1
url2,filename2
...
url3000,filename3000
```

I wrote the following code using snippets I found here:

```
while read p; do

a=$( echo $p | cut -d',' -f1 )
b=$( echo $p | cut -d',' -f2 )

ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel quiet -stats -i ${a} ${b}.mp3 &

done <downloadmp3.txt
```

The issue that I have is that my script downloads around 500 mp3s out of the 3000 (some entirely, some partially) and then just stops. Any advice on what changes to make would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown any logs that would hint at what the underlying issue is, but you're essentially launching 3000 processes at the same time, which might have unexpected consequences (e.g., the remote server terminating the connection). Since the `&` puts the job in the background, the loop should exit fairly quickly once all `ffmpeg` processes have spun up, but then you have 3000 jobs running…

I would instead recommend using [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) to download *n* files at a time.

```
parallel --dry-run --colsep ',' ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -stats -i {1} -c copy {2}.mp3 :::: downloadmp3.txt
```

This reads the text file and processes each line, splitting the columns by `,`. You can then use the column values as `{1}`, `{2}`, and so on.

It would run the following commands in parallel, with at most *n* jobs running at one time. By default *n* is equal to the number of CPU cores:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -stats -i url1 -c copy filename1.mp3
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -stats -i url2 -c copy filename2.mp3
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -stats -i url3000 -c copy filename3000.mp3
```

Remove the `--dry-run` when this prints what you want.

You can add `--joblog jobs.txt` to have it create a logfile, and you could also add `--eta` or `--progress` to print out some estimates as to when the jobs will be finished. The number of parallel jobs can be set with `-j`.

Note that I've added `-c copy` since you usually don't want to re-encode the audio stream if the URL already points to an existing MP3 file. If your input is not MP3, you might want to leave out the `-c copy` again. And I changed `quiet` to `error` since you probably want errors to be shown.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Where can I add the "n" to specify the number of parallel jobs?

Comment: As I wrote, “the number of parallel jobs can be set with `-j`.”